# Instantiate class from variable name not working

Tags: php

```
$controller = 'DefaultController';
require('app/controllers/'.$controller.'.php');
$object = new $controller;
```

This is failing at the `new $controller`, but not at the `require`.. I really have no ideas here

> Fatal error: Class 'DefaultController' not found in C:\wamp\www\controller\index.php on line 31

```
app/controllers/DefaultController.php

<?php
namespace App\Controllers;

/**
* DefaultController
*/
class DefaultController
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        # code...
    }

    public function index() {

    }
}
```

**edit:** I've added the namespace, still the same result

```
$controller = 'DefaultController';
require('app/controllers/'.$controller.'.php');
$controller = 'App\Controller\\'.$controller;
$object = new $controller;
```

`Fatal error: Class 'App\Controller\DefaultController' not found in C:\wamp\www\controller\index.php on line 33`

**edit 2: ah yes.. it's *Controllers* not Controller**

Comment: Show us the contents of `app/controllers/DefaultController.php`...!?

Comment: Because `app/controllers/DefaultController.php` exists but it doesn't have a class named `DefaultController` would be my guess. Include your code.

Comment: Without posting **Defaultcontroller.php** we can't help you.

Comment: Added DefaultController.php, it all looks right to me so I didn't include it

Comment: DefaultCOntroller class is in namespace

Comment: If you use a namespace, the namespace prefix MUST be prepended to the class name before the **new** create an instance.

Comment: @Edde In PHP terms: you need to use the *Fully Qualified Name* of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class name is `App\Controllers\DefaultController`, not `DefaultController`.

```
require 'app/controllers/DefaultController.php';
$controller = 'App\Controllers\DefaultController';
$object = new $controller;
```

How you square that away with an autoloader/`require` statement is up to you.

Comment: Added this to the same result, please see edit

Comment: Double check that namespace name!

Comment: aha! thanks :) tired eyes aren't helping me today

Answer (score 3):

Because you're using the wrong namespace.

Try with

```
$controller = 'App\Controllers\DefaultController';
```

Comment: Added that, same result

Comment: So does it work with Controllers instead of Controller?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a namespace, the namespace prefix MUST be prepended to the class name before creating an instance with **new**.

You class exists inside the namespace and its name carries the namespace name.

Comment: I believe you're looking for the term *Fully Qualified Name*.

Comment: Exactly! Thanks! I'm an old man and my memory sometimes is not that good! LOL